# How to make a bot display a user's info if another user pings that user discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to get my bot to display a users info if a user types 'profile? [name of other user]'.

```py
if message.content == 'profile?' + user.mention:
   x=display_players_smiles(str(user.mention))            
   y=display_players_frowns(str(user.mention))
   embedVar = discord.Embed(title= str(user.mention), description="This is their profile", color=0x0210ff)
   embedVar.add_field(name="Smiles", value=str(x), inline=False)
   embedVar.add_field(name="Frowns", value=str(y), inline=False)
   await message.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
```

I tried to use user.mention but it gave me an error.

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the `on_message` events instead of commands? It'd be much easier for you

Comment: There is no reason, and I wouldn't mind using commands instead. I just don't know how to use commands for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no reason for you to use commands Ill give you an example

```py
@bot.command() # Or `client.command()` - depends how you named your bot instance
async def profile(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    x = display_players_smiles(user.mention)            
    y = display_players_frowns(user.mention)
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title=user.mention, description="This is their profile", color=0x0210ff)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Smiles", value=str(x), inline=False)
    embedVar.add_field(name="Frowns", value=str(y), inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embedVar)
```

A couple of things worth mentioning:

- You need `intents.members` enabled
- At the end of the `on_message` event you need to add

```py
await bot.process_commands(message) # Or `client.process..` - depends how you named it
```

- Remember to use `commands.Bot`, not `discord.Client`, also remember to use only ONE, not both.

Take a look at the [commands introduction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) it will hopefully clear up some things for you.

Here another useful link on how to enable intents & privileged intents, [link heer](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html)

Comment: I keep getting this error 
```Ignoring exception in on_message```

whenever i try to run the code.

Comment: What's the error? Also you're supposed to delete the `profile` command in the `on_message` event as you have it as a command

Comment: What is eo? And yes i removed my old command for profile and this is the only one i have now, but i still get the same error.

Comment: I put that in the comments, I don't know how you named your bot instance, you may called `client`. Take a look at your code and look if you're using `client` or `bot`

Comment: I also wrote that in the answer. You're supposed to use `commands.Bot` not `discord.Client`. It'll make it easier for both, you and me if you read the answer, take a look at the code, try to understand it. Visit the links, that's why I put them for

Comment: Simply change `discord.Client` to `commands.Bot`, also you should import it like so `from discord.ext import commands`. It's in one of the links I provided for you.

Comment: I just realized that this code doesnt allow the user to check their own profile as a user has to be pinged how do i fix that to allow the user to just do the profile command without any other user mentioned and see their own profile.

Comment: Make the `user` optional with a default value of `None`, in the command check with an if-statement if the `user` variable is `None`, if it is, `user = ctx.author`